# Is it possible to publish expo after install dependency?

Tags: expo, publish

after build expo, i released at play store.

After this i installed dependency to add useful function.
("react-native-draggable-flatlist")

is it possible to publish?

If this is not possible, I have to remake apk.

oh, and if i built expo(making apk file), can i publish?
I didn't take any action before build.

Answer (score 0):

***yes you can*** after building expo released `apk`
If you make any of the following changes in app.json, you will need to re-build the binaries for your app for the change to take effect: Increment the Expo SDK Version Change anything under the ios, android, or notification keys Change your app splash Change your app icon Change your app name Change your app owner Change your app scheme List item Heading
see the doc [here](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/publishing/)